# SQL: Retrieve value from a column that occurred least number of times

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table which have a single field. and it have a values like (3,7,9,11,7,11)
Now I want a query which will pick the value that occurred least number of times and if there is a tie with minimum occurrences then use the smallest number

In this case the answer will be 3.

Comment: What do you mean by "minimum weightage"?

Comment: minimum weightage means the value should be minimum

Comment: So, in the event of a tie of appearing the least number of times, it must also be the smallest value. Is that what you mean?

Comment: yes Colin That's what I wanna Mean..

Comment: You might want to specify which database server you're using. A few of the answers below are SQL Server specific.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Something like this:

```
SELECT TOP 1 COUNT(*), myField
FROM myTable
GROUP BY (myField)
ORDER BY COUNT(*) ASC
```

**ADDITIONAL:** And to taking into account the tie-breaker situation:

```
SELECT TOP 1 COUNT(*), myField
FROM myTable
GROUP BY (myField)
ORDER BY COUNT(*) ASC, myField ASC
```

Comment: Updated answer to take into account the tie-breaker aspect of the question.

Comment: Thanks This works in the SQL server exactly the way I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

In `MySQL` and `PostgreSQL`:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
        SELECT  field, COUNT(*) AS cnt
        FROM    mytable
        GROUP BY
                field
        ) q
ORDER BY
        cnt, field
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Hi Quassnoi U r answer is 98% right Only one need to add <AS tst> as an alias name before the ORDER BY clause.
Because in MySql Every derived table must have its own alias.
Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using SQL Server: if you have ties for the least frequent number, and you want all ties returned, then you could do something like this:

```
DECLARE @temp table (
    count int,
    myField int
)

INSERT @temp
SELECT COUNT(*), myField
FROM myTable
GROUP BY (myField)

DECLARE @minCount int

SELECT @minCount = MIN(count)
FROM @temp

SELECT count, myField
FROM @temp
WHERE count = @minCount
```